# Favicon not changing

Tags: magento-1.9, favicons

I have uploaded an image of a new favicon in the following:

```
System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> and uploaded it into Favicon Icon.
```

I have applied it to both Store View & Website View.

I have waited a while and yet no signs of it being changed. Could anyone please advise me what I should do in this case?

Comment: Have you clear your cache from system->cache managment ?

Comment: you can check the path of Favicon and replace your favicon there with same name.

Comment: Check in different browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can check below things

clear cache from `system->cache management`

If above change not work then follow below steps

1) go to `app/code/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/page/html/head.phtml`

2) find below line

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
```

If its not there then replace or add this line

Answer (score 0):

Using ftp ypu can also change favicon

Go to `skin/frontend/Your-package/Your-theme/` upload favicon here give name `favicon.ico`

Comment: I have the following: 

/skin/frontend/sns_toronto2/default ... then subfolders:

- assets, aw-blog, aw-hdu3, css, images, js, less, sns

Where do I go then?

Comment: Upload favicon.ico file here /skin/frontend/sns_toronto2/default

Comment: Are you sure? 

Because when I go under /skin/frontend/sns_toronto2/default/images .. I have a folder for ico .. will it still need to go under 

/skin/frontend/sns_toronto2/default ?

Comment: Go to your page press cntrl+u check in source there is path of favicon.ico upload favicon.ico there

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same kind of issue. This error might occur after upgrading the Magento version. These are the steps I followed to resolve this.

**Delete the previous icon entries in the database.**

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE `path` = 'design/head/shortcut_icon';
```

**Add the favicon again from the backend**

```
Content > Configuration > Edit > HTML Head > Favicon Icon
```